# Launch screen delay works in iOS Simulator but not Device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, splash-screen

I've set my launch screen to only display for 1 second using the code below sleep(1); in the app delegate, but when testing directly on a device, I have to wait for the full 5 seconds.

Every time I run a test using an iPhone, or an iPad, I have to wait the full 5 second default before the app will load, however, it works great in the simulator.

If I unplug the iPhone cable, the sleep() function works on the devices. Is there a setting in xCode for this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
       sleep(1);

...

}
```

Comment: why do you want to make it sleep ?

Comment: I was under the impression from a tutorial I read, that sleep(1) set the launch screen delay?

Comment: No, it won't set the launch screen delay, it just further delays the app launch. You don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delay the launch screen this is not the recommended method. This just delays the whole process.

I recommend you add a new `viewController` to the very beginning of your project which will show immediately after the launch screen with a `UIImageView` containing the exact same image as the launch Image.

Then add a delay from there before switching to the original first screen. This way you can even add a new different kind of transition to the launch image.

```
#import "OrginalController.h"

- (void) gotoOrginalFirstScreen
{
        // This function will take you to your oringinal first screen
        // from the temporary screen with the launch image
        OrginalController *controller = [[OrginalController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrginalController" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add this line to call the transition and the delay
    [self performSelector:@"gotoOrginalFirstScreen" withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}
```

Comment: Is that still recommended if I want to set the overall delay to 1 second?

Comment: i believe its a bad practise to set delay in app delegate. although im not expert to advice

Comment: ok, just trying to get the delay to go away. I don't need a 5 second launch screen. Maybe it's just an xCode bug. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @jhilgert00: You can't completely make the delay go away. By using `sleep` or presenting other launch view you are only making it longer. The delay is longer when launching app through XCode because of debugger, it needs time to attach to process.

Answer (score 1):

you can display the launch screen without putting it to sleep itself. You don't need a separate view controller also. This method will work anywhere and wont trouble you also.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splashscreen.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 324, 480);
[window addSubview:imageView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self performSelector:@selector(firstscreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
return YES;     
}


-(void)firstscreen
{
        // Load some View

}
```

this you can put it in you application delegate this will show your splash image for 1 sec after which the next screen will be loaded.